# AEM Resources missing sling:resourceType

Tags: aem, sling

My content repository over a 2 year span has accumulated many obsolete component resources. The component nodes are missing sling:resourceType property. These component nodes looks like this:

[image: missing sling:resourceType]

Due to such bad resources, the page is throwing below exception:

```
14.09.2017 12:33:21.079 *ERROR* [172.21.142.98 [1505392399461] GET /content/xx/en_ca/home.html HTTP/1.1] 
org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource Paragraph, 
path=/content/xx/en_ca/home/jcr:content/par-sidebar/contentbox_c540/rightRailContentPar/contentbox_f1fd, 
type=nt:unstructured, cssClass=default, column=0/0, diffInfo=[null], 
resource=[JcrNodeResource, type=nt:unstructured, superType=null, 
path=/content/xx/en_ca/home/jcr:content/par-sidebar/contentbox_c540/rightRailContentPar/contentbox_f1fd]
```

Further digging I found someone had written a [tool to cleanup](https://github.com/npeltier/org.apache.sling.typecleanup) such obsolete resources.

While it is easy to query and cleanup such invalid nodes, my question how did such resources end up in repository? I tried to simulate by moving components, deleting components from page but in vain. There is no custom scripting that is removing sling:resourceType. Is this issue faced only by me? Or is there any product issue/usecase that can clear the type of resource?

I am running AEM 6.0 SP2.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem in multiple projects, so I'm also very interested in the cause of these issue. It's difficult to debug, because the source they are coming is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a known product bug to be fixed for future AEM. This is the response I got from daycare ticket:

There are several known issues related to sling:resourceType in AEM 6.0 SP2 and later but the one that I could find nearest to the scenario you have mentioned occurs when the components are copied and pasted.

It removes/breaks the sling:resourceType property. This issue is covered under the internal id -CQ-4212306, the fix for which will be a part of the future version of AEM.